# How do I play a sound when the screen is locked on Android in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a simple app that upon render plays a sound after a few seconds.

Everything works except that if I lock the screen, the app will not play the sound until I unlock it again.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm working with:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import Sound from 'react-native-sound'; //for the bell sound

class SoundTest extends Component {

  componenWillMount(){
    setTimeout(this.playSound(), 5000);
  }

  playSound() {
      let s = new Sound('bell.wav','', (e) => {
        if (e) {
          console.log('error', e);
        } else {
          console.log('duration', s.getDuration());
          s.play();
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hear some sound after a few!</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SoundTest', () => SoundTest);

// Works great if the screen is on / not locked
```

Is there some way to play the sound regardless of whether the screen is locked or not?

Comment: There must be a configuration on the android world, for iOS I only added a config on the `Info.plist` file and that did the trick, however I don't know how to do this on Android, I will follow this thread as I will need to do this very soon xD